# Complex integral of $\cfrac{e^{2z}}{z^4}$

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, complex-integration

I want to calculate $\displaystyle\int\cfrac{e^{2z}}{z^4}dz$ where $ |z| \le 1$.

I write $z=x+iy$ then split the integral into real and imaginary parts but could not find a way to parametrize $z$ or to get rid of $e^{2z}$.

Any ideas would be very helpful.

Comment: I don't really understand your question. If you're looking for an area integral, then you're going to have a *ton* of convergence issues and likely need to look at a particular principal value. If you're asking about the contour integral around the circle, then there are techniques to handle it using residues.

Comment: I came across with this problem exactly like above. If we assume that it is a contour integral, how do we solve it?

Comment: By using residues.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming the $|z|\leq 1$ should be a $|z|=1$.

In which case we have by Cauchy's integral formula 
$$
\int_{|z|=1}\frac{e^{2z}}{z^4}\mathrm dz=\frac{2\pi i}{3!}\frac{d^3}{dz^3} e^{2z}\bigg\vert_0\\
=\frac{16\pi i}{6}=\frac{8\pi i}{3}
$$
Of course you may also use the Residue theorem for higher order poles if you would like as well.